# Custom URL for pre-production environments GitHub Actions

Tags: github-actions

I deploy my react-app through GitHub Actions. GitHub Actions generates a random URL.

How can I change this url to be something like `pr${steps.pr.outputs.pull_request_number}.azurewebsites.net`?

Could someone guide me on this please?

Comment: Can you please clarify what URL is generated by GitHub Actions? Where is that used? How would you like it to change?

Comment: Something like pr39.azurewebsites.net?